# Javascript - style of terminating execution of a function when calling a callback

Tags: javascript, node.js

We often need to make sure that execution won't return to a function after a callback has been made.  **My question is, are there any subtle differences in effect between these two styles, or are they entirely the same? :**

```
function myFunction(foo, callback) {
    if(foo) {
      callback(err, true); //Here
      return;              //Here
    }
    bar();
}
```

And:

```
function myFunction(foo, callback) {
    if(foo) {
      return callback(err, true); //Here
    }
    bar();
}
```

EDIT: Sorry, I realised that my question wasn't very clear. I'm talking about situations where I don't care what is being returned (because it won't be consumed synchronously), but where the return is simply to ensure that execution does not continue in the function, after the callback function has completed.

Comment: This question can be reduced to whether you should return something from your function or not.

Comment: @tracevipin - well, the function does not need to return anything, but it doesn't matter if it does return something.  I'm not sure this question can simply be reduced to that though.

Comment: @tracevipin - as an example take a look at the last code block on this page : http://docs.nodejitsu.com/articles/getting-started/control-flow/what-are-callbacks - seems to be that the error callback does not need to 'return' anything, yet they are using the second style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It entirely depends on what you want to return.

If you want to return the value returned by the callback use second method else first

Comment: Hmm, yeah I think I need to phrase my question a little better.  I'm rather talking about situations where I don't care what is being returned (because it won't be consumed synchronously), but where the return is simply to ensure that execution does not continue in the function, after the callback function has completed.

Comment: Then the two are exactly the same.

Comment: @UpTheCreek In that case first option will be better because it is more explicit

Comment: @ArunPJohny - thanks. yeah, I was preferring the second because it's less verbose. But I think I'll go with the first as from now on, as it avoids ambiguities as have been raised in this answer.

Answer (score 1):

As a matter of coding style, if one wants to avoid `return`s within a function, which some people consider a Bad Thing, then

```
function myFunction(foo, callback) {
    if(foo) {
        callback(err, true);
    } else {
        bar();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah I agree, but personally I don't like conditional blocks that span the entire function (which could be large) as they are harder to read and lead to more braces and indenting.

Comment: `return foo ? callback(err,true) : bar();`??

Comment: heh :) For short functions I have no problem with the if else, but in longer ones where you are hunting for matching braces it's a bit of a pain.